# Why bother getting larger soul gems in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What difference do gems make in enchanting weapons?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/43515/what-difference-do-gems-make-in-enchanting-weapons)

I have a filled black soul gem and I am not sure what value it gives me over a petty soul. When enchanting, I see the same "Target takes 11 points of frost damage" message no matter which soul gem I choose to use. Why should I bother collecting larger gems and filling them?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of a question I posted awhile back.  I'll look that up for you.

Comment: Found it:  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/43515/6274

Comment: Perfect; thanks. For some reason I couldn't find your question when searching.

Comment: It's ok.  Happens to me all the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For armor, the quality of the soul gem affects its magnitude. For weapons, the quality affects how many charges it can hold.

A Petty Soul Gem filled with a petty soul with only give you [1/12 the effect](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Enchanting_Effects#Apparel) as Black/Grand Soul Gem with a grand soul. The means a weapon dealing frost damage based on a Petty Soul Gem will need to be refilled 12 times as often and will require the expenditure of at least 12 souls to do so, whereas a weapon enchanted using a Grand Soul Gem may only need a single, powerful soul to recharge once during that time.

It's not as pronounced an effect as for armor, definitely, but it's still nice to not have to recharge as often.

Comment: "How many charges it can hold" was the crucial bit. Thanks much!